# Mac OS X Terminal getting wrong SSH path?

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal

In Mac OS X terminal, I am logging in to a remote server via ssh with a dsa key pair. When I execute this command:

```
ssh -v -l root -p 22 [remote ip address]
```

I see in the debug code that Terminal is looking for my key in

```
/var/root/.ssh/
```

The actual path is:

```
/Users/danny/.ssh/
```

If I execute this command:

```
ssh -v -i /Users/danny/.ssh/inno_dsa -l root -p [remote IP address]
```

... then I get in fine.

So my question is there a way to tell terminal to autmatically look in /Users/danny/.ssh/ so I don't always have to explicitly specify the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myremoteroot
HostName [remote IP address]
User root
IdentityFile /Users/danny/.ssh/inno_dsa
```

Then connect by executing `ssh myremoteroot`.

(Btw, why are you explicitly specifying the default port?)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the info. This sort of works and it's a great solution. When i did not add port 22, it would not connect. Note that in the new config file, I had to add `port 22` as well. So now it seems like it's connecting but I get `Address [remote IP] maps to vps.mydomain.com but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!` so it seems like it does make the connection but then I am not allowed in. I did some googling around and found `GSSAPIAuthentication no` but that did not seem to fix it.

Comment: It turns out there was a config file in /private/etc so once I added the code to that, it now works fine connecting with `ssh myremoteroot`. However, I am not sure if that's best practices to alter that file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Macs in particular. In general a global config file might be overwritten when you upgrade software --- I don't know whether OS X specifically would do that.

Comment: Ok thanks. It turns out I was in terminal as root so it was not writing to the correct config file. Once I was back down as my user in terminal It seemed to recognize the config file but I am getting another error. I think I am going to open a new question for that though.

Comment: Got it figured out, error on my part I had `User Danny` instead of my remote user which is of course root. So changing it to `User Root` as you have above fixed this. Thanks again!